# custom Shiro realm - who does the actual authentication

Tags: shiro

when sub classing shiro's `AuthorizingRealm` (or only `AuthenticationRealm`) by overriding

```
protected AuthenticationInfo doGetAuthenticationInfo(AuthenticationToken token) throws AuthenticationException {
}
```

Is it my job to check that the credentials provided in the AuthenticationToken actually match?

Or am I supposed to return the `AuthenticationInfo` with the `principals` resolved from the `AuthenticationToken` and the correct password for the given credentials and shiro will compare them on its own somewhere within the flow of the Subject.login(AuthenticationToken) call?

Answer (score 3):

The Javadocs for [`AuthenticatingRealm.doGetAuthenticationInfo()`](https://shiro.apache.org/static/1.3.2/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/realm/AuthenticatingRealm.html#doGetAuthenticationInfo-org.apache.shiro.authc.AuthenticationToken-) state (emphasis mine):

> Retrieves authentication data from an implementation-specific datasource (RDBMS, LDAP, etc) for the given authentication token.
>
> **For most datasources, this means just 'pulling' authentication data for an associated subject/user and nothing more and letting Shiro do the rest.** But in some systems, this method could actually perform EIS specific log-in logic in addition to just retrieving data - it is up to the Realm implementation.

The method `AuthenticatingRealm.getAuthenticationInfo()` first calls  `doGetAuthenticationInfo()` then subsequently calls `assertCredentialsMatch()` using the configured `credentialsMatcher`:

```java
public final AuthenticationInfo getAuthenticationInfo(AuthenticationToken token) throws AuthenticationException {

    AuthenticationInfo info = getCachedAuthenticationInfo(token);
    if (info == null) {
        //otherwise not cached, perform the lookup:
        info = doGetAuthenticationInfo(token);
        log.debug("Looked up AuthenticationInfo [{}] from doGetAuthenticationInfo", info);
        if (token != null && info != null) {
            cacheAuthenticationInfoIfPossible(token, info);
        }
    } else {
        log.debug("Using cached authentication info [{}] to perform credentials matching.", info);
    }

    if (info != null) {
        assertCredentialsMatch(token, info);
    } else {
        log.debug("No AuthenticationInfo found for submitted AuthenticationToken [{}].  Returning null.", token);
    }

    return info;
}
```

So depending on how typical your Realm implementation is, you might want to avoid checking the `AuthenticationToken`'s credentials in the `doGetAuthenticationInfo()` method, because the `getAuthenticationInfo()` template method already contains a step to ensure the submitted credentials match.

To specifically address your question if it is your responsibility "to check that the credentials provided in the AuthenticationToken actually match", the answer is **yes, but not in the `doGetAuthenticationInfo()` method**. Typically you would perform the credentials comparison within an implementation of the [`CredentialsMatcher`](https://shiro.apache.org/static/current/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/shiro/authc/credential/CredentialsMatcher.html) interface, as described [here](https://shiro.apache.org/realm.html#Realm-CredentialsMatching).

Answer (score 0):

Inside doGetAuthenticationInfo(...) you need to verify that the user has provided you with authentication proof.

Here is a pseudo-coded example of what you might do:

```
protected AuthenticationInfo doGetAutheticationInfo(AuthenticationToken token) {
  if(token instanceof UsernamePasswordToken) {
    String username = token.getUsername();
    // Look up the user by the provide username
    UserRecord userRecord = lookupUserRecord(username);
    // No record found - don't know who this is
    if (userRecord == null) {
      throw new UnknownAccountException();
    }
    // Check for other things, like a locked account, expired password, etc.

    // Verify the user
    SimpleAuthenticationInfo sai = new SimpleAuthenticationInfo(userRecord.getPrincipal(), userRecord.getHashedCredentials(), userRecord.getCredentialsSalt(), getName());
    boolean successfulAuthentication = getCredentialsMatcher().doCredentialsMatch(token, sai);

    if(successfulAuthentication) {
       // Check for anything else that might prevent login (expired password, locked account, etc
       if (other problems) {
           throw new CredentialsException(); // Or something more specific
       }
       // Success!
       return sai;
    } else {
       // Bad password
       throw new IncorrectCredentialsException();
    }
  }
  // Don't know what to do with this token
  throw new CredentialsException();
}
```

You'll have to write lookupUserRecord(username) or something similar to go lookup the user information including his hashed and salted credentials.

Answer (score 0):

doGetAuthenticationInfo is the main method where authentication is done. SO if you override it generally you are overriding authentication process. If you want to use the process that was defined for that reealm and do some extra things better call super class method first then get its info and then use it so you will not have to change anything. Also in case of jdbcrealm sqls in shiro.ini are automatically mapped. and they will not be changed until you override
setAuthenticationQuery, setUserRolesQuery, etc

You can easily call following method to simulate the actual process then customize it.

```
AuthenticationInfo  info = super.doGetAuthenticationInfo(token);
```

Note, that super is a reference to the parent, but super() is it's constructor.

like:

```
public class CustomJdbcRealm extends JdbcRealm 
{
    @Override
    protected AuthenticationInfo doGetAuthenticationInfo(AuthenticationToken token) throws AuthenticationException 
    {

       AuthenticationInfo  info = super.doGetAuthenticationInfo(token);
      // Your own code here 
    }
}
```